# Magento 2.1 Custom template/div within product page to pull in product data

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to insert a `<div>` into a product page which does this.

```
<div class="thisdiv" id="mydiv" data-sku="<?php echo $item->getSku(); ?>">
```

I am ok with putting the `<div>` into a custom template file and then using the layout XML to display that, but how would I get the product sku of the product to appear in the tag?

I've just got this so far in my template file and just get a blank page.

```
<?php
    $item = $block->getProduct();
?>
<div class="thisdiv" id="mydiv" data-sku="<?php echo $item->getSku(); ?>">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it myself but for my reference...

Template file goes here:

Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view

Template looks like this...

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $_code = $block->getAtCode();
    $_className = $block->getCssClass();
    $_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
    $_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
    $_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
?>

<div class="thisdiv" id="mydiv" data-sku="<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>">
```

catalog_product_view.xml in Magento_Catalog/layout has this...

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="mydiv" template="product/view/mydiv.phtml" after="-" />
```